# send request from PHP to Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, api, jwt

I know the idea of JWT. But I have to work with both, PHP as a client which will send data to Node.js API and receive data back. 
I know it is trivial if you are using JWT inside PHP only or Node.js. But is it possible to send from PHP to Node.js API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is, the validation may be an security issue in some cases, but you could do it with as secret or using  certificates.

Comment: thanks for reply @desoras . Is it  a big deal or not much different from usual jwt implementation ?

Comment: If you use an secret, like some string no, using certificates is a little bit more complicated, you must create the token with the private key and verify with the public.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking it will not be possible . I will go with a secret string and hopefully it will work